# Facebook failing to pick up the very first img tag as the main thumbnail

Tags: html, facebook, image

http://new.sonikastudios.com

I tried everything to get my logo image to be picked as the thumbnail, but this is eluding me! It keeps defaulting to either the Twitter or Facebook button when I try to share this link on Facebook.

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://new.sonikastudios.com/images/sonika_logo.png"/>

<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://new.sonikastudios.com/images/sonika_logo.png" />
```

Those are specified on the  section.. not to mention the img tag is straight-foward:

```
<a href="/" title="Sonika Studios Inc."><img src="/images/sonika_logo.png" title="Sonika Studios Inc." alt="Sonika Studios Inc." /></a>
```

What am I missing to make my logo the main thumbnail for Facebook shares? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you specified the MIME type as `image/jpeg` when your image is actually a PNG.

Just remove the `type` attribute - it's not required by [Facebook Share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share).

Comment: Now it picks up NONE of the images... not even the two Twitter iamges. But at least it's changed something! 

I found that bit about the image size and ratio restriction, so I'm thinking that might be it - my logo is a bit on the long side, but I have a square version so I'm going to upload that and see what happens. 

Thank you for that link.

Comment: So it was the size that was the issue. I had to upload another image in the images folder (although not displayed anywhere on the page) and now it works.. Thank you for pointing me to the right page!